# Change char variable values and print using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to change `char fruit`variable value from `Apple` to `Orange` using pointer technique please can anybody help me to solve my problem.
Here is the the code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char fruit='Apple';
  char *ptr_fruit;
  ptr_fruit=&fruit;
  *ptr_fruit='Orange';

  cout<< fruit;

    system("PAUSE");

}
```

Comment: Your types are wrong: `'` is for (single) `char`, you probably mean `const char* fruit = "Apple"`.

Comment: stay away from hacks like `system("PAUSE")`

Comment: @Jarod42 no I have not type wrong please let me know the logic behind `const` and why you are making `fruit` variable as a pointer.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode is this anything bad with this? what you suggest to use.

Comment: @MuhammadSohail something that isn't platform dependent and unsafe. Like `std::cin.get()`.

Comment: @MuhammadSohail: `'c'` is a single char. `"c"` is a c-string (which decays to `const char*`). You have also (since C++14) `"c"s` for a `std::string`. `'aa'` is invalid whereas `"aa"` or `"aa"s` are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should review the basics of C++. And abandon char* for std::string. Anyway, some tips if you really want to use this approach:

1. Declare large enough buffer for your fruits `char fruit[50] = "Apple"`
2. Use strncpy for copying and some temp containers.

Comment: Why we need `strncpy` for this purpose variable and pointers are also a holder, please guide me.

Comment: No, pointers are not holders. Char* points you to the first character of your string. As for strncpy - please refer to online documentation. It basically copies contents of char arrays (always use strncpy, not strcpy - else you'll probably get unexpected overflows).

Answer (score 1):

Is this something you want ?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   char const *fruit="Apple";

   char const **ptr_fruit;
   ptr_fruit = &fruit;
  *ptr_fruit = "Orange";

   std::cout << fruit;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Conversion from `string` constant to `char*` is deprecated .

Comment: @rakeb.void: No, it's illegal.

Answer (score 0):

1: You declare an array like this

```
char Fruit[] = "Apple";
```

See the brackets and double quotes?

What you are doing is to declare a char variable, because when you put something in `""`(double quotes), it is considered as a string, when you put it in `''`(Single quotes), it is considered as character by the compile.

2: When you say `*ptr_fruit`,compiler treats it as `ptr_fruit[0]`. So you will get error in that line too.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
const char* fruit = "Apple";
const char** ptr_fruit = &fruit;
*ptr_fruit = "Orange"; // now fruit is "Orange"
```

but I think following is easier to understand by the introduction of a `typedef` to avoid the `**` which may be confusing.

```
using c_string = const char*; // or `typedef const char* c_string;`

c_string fruit = "Apple";
c_string* ptr_fruit = &fruit;
*ptr_fruit = "Orange"; // now fruit is "Orange"
```

The two code snippet are equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

change it like this
char *fruit="Apple";
char *ptr_fruit=fruit;

it should work

Comment: simple char variable stores one character. In this scenario you need pointer or character array or string

Comment: if this answer helped you please do remember to mark it as answer happy coding :)

Comment: yes sure I will but here needed some more instructions what is difference '' between  "" when we dealing with char datatype, also why I need to implement with array while I do same thing with `int` datatype same  code give me the correct result.

Comment: At least put some _basic_ formatting in your post. Come on.